# CORS problem when accessing local file via Javascript FileReader() in Safari Web Worker

Tags: javascript, cors, web-worker

I need to process local file with Javascript in web browser. The process is tedious that comprises a lot of `RegEx.exec()` and would take some time to finish, so I put both `FileReader()` and handler in web worker. The final product works fine in **Google Chrome** and **Microsoft Edge**, but have problems with **macOS Safari**.

This (simplified) Javascript code fails to work in macOS Safari 16.5.1, when the HTML file is directly loaded from local filesystem via `file:///path/to/localfile.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script id="worker" type="javascript/worker">
    self.onmessage = function(evt) {
        var file = evt.data;
        var filereader = new FileReaderSync();
        console.log(filereader.readAsText(file,'UTF-8'));
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function on_change(evt) {
        const workerblob = new Blob(
            [document.querySelector('#worker').textContent],
            {type:"text/javascript"});
        new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(workerblob)).postMessage(evt.target.files[0]);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="fileselector" type="file" onchange="on_change(event)">
</body>
</html>
```

Safari Javascript console showed 3 error messages:

- Cannot load `blob:null/ff4c37bb-8ddb-4082-a492-425423e35ef9`.
- Failed to load resource: **Cross origin requests are not allowed when using same-origin fetch mode**.
- `NotReadableError`: The I/O read operation failed.

So it's some sort of CORS problem, but I've no idea to tell the browser to "allow origin", since the resource to be loaded is a local file.

Is there any work around ?

More details:

1. It works as expected if the HTML is hosted by a HTTP server and loaded via regular HTTP/HTTPS request.
2. Both Chrome and Edge won't complain about CORS problem is the HTML file is loaded from local filesystem.
3. Safari will only complain about CORS problem when `FileReader()` is called within web worker.

I'm supposed to deliver the HTML file as final product since the client doesn't want another web server. So I need it to work when loaded from local filesystem.

P.S. *Yes I've tried `FileReader()` and get the same result. In fact I'm using `FileReader()` in my final product and just want to simplify the post. It's a CORS related issue so both `FileReader()` and `FileReaderSync()` shall work in the same way.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can repro, on both latest stable and TP, and I did open [this report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=258443).

Quoting my own note in that report:

> The issue seems to be that the fetch request made to access the blob's data goes through cross-origin checks, however the Blob should be by essence same origin, since it's supposed to be "in memory".
> This happens for Workers created from a data: URL, as well as for the ones created from a blob: URL in a file:// document.
>
> The weird thing is that it seems to work fine for opaque origin iframes (sandboxed or data: URL).

Unfortunately, since Safari still doesn't support transferring `ReadableStream` objects, there doesn't seem to be any good workaround.

The best would obviously be to avoid being in an opaque origin from the get-go, but if it's not possible, the less awful workaround would be to read your file from the main thread to an `ArrayBuffer` object, and then transfer that `ArrayBuffer` to your worker and [decode it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) there. The I/O work should still be done in parallel, so it would hopefully not block your UI.

```js
/**
 * For this live Snippet, we use a data: URI instead of file:// + blob:
 * The same issue normally happens here.
 *
 * Side note:
 * Do not create a new Worker for every new File.
 * Start only one and reuse it.
 */
const workerdata = encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('#worker').textContent);
const worker = new Worker("data:text/javascript," + workerdata);
worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => console.log(data);
async function on_change(evt) {
  const buffer = await evt.target.files[0].arrayBuffer();
  worker.postMessage(buffer, [buffer]);
};
```

```html
<script id="worker" type="javascript/worker">
  self.onmessage = function(evt) {
    var buffer = evt.data;
    postMessage(new TextDecoder().decode(buffer));
  };
</script>
<input id="fileselector" type="file" onchange="on_change(event)">
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. So it is a WebKit related problem. Please note that this only happens when loading the HTML directly from 'file://'; loading via regular HTTP from web host will work as expected. I guess I'd just tell the client to avoid directly launching the local HTML file in Safari, and host that HTML somewhere in their already existed web server instead. Since I've already packed all the minified JS and SVG into one single file, so it should be an easy task.

Comment: Yes, this is a Safari/WebKit bug. It is supposed to work. It actually happens when the Worker as its origin set to `null`. This can happen when the original document itself as its origin set to an opaque origin (e.g because it's loaded from a `data:` URL, or, indeed, from `file://`), or if the Worker's main script is served from a `data:` URL.